# When dealing with arrays of C structs, is (*(data+i)).member the same as data[i].member?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I am new to dealing with structs, particularly arrays of structs.

I am wondering if this is correct.

```
(*(data+i)).member == data[i].member  ?
```

Comment: Generally speaking yes but why write obfuscated code?

Comment: If you're going to do the pointer offset arithmetic (there are times when that actually makes sense, even if simplified examples like the above make it look really bad), then use the structure dereference operator. E.g. `(data+offset)->member`

Comment: @acfrancis I was confusing myself with the whole pointer dereferencing issue.  Just needed some clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the two are guaranteed to be equivalent.  In particular, the C language standard defines array subscripting `data[i]` in terms of pointer arithmetic -- `data[i]` is equivalent to be `*(data + i)` *by definition*.

From C99 §6.5.2.1/2:

> A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets `[]` is a subscripted
>   designation of an element of an array object. The definition of the subscript operator `[]`
>   is that `E1[E2]` is identical to `(*((E1)+(E2)))`. Because of the conversion rules that
>   apply to the binary `+` operator, if `E1` is an array object (equivalently, a pointer to the
>   initial element of an array object) and `E2` is an integer, `E1[E2]` designates the `E2`-th
>   element of `E1` (counting from zero).

Note that since the binary `+` operator is commutative, that means that `a[b]` is equivalent to `b[a]`, even if `b` is an integer and `a` is a pointer or array, so expressions like `4["a character array"]` are legal and well-defined.

That said, writing `*(data + i)` is *usually* considered bad style (and `4["a character array"]` would almost always be considered bad style, unless you're trying to win the International Obfuscated C Code Contest).  Unless you have a good reason, just write `data[i]` and be done with it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is true that

```
*(data+i)
```

accesses the same data as

```
data[i]
```

but it is generally less readable. It is just pointer arithmetic. The `.member` part is not really important, it is the pointer dereference and array index notation equivalence that matters.

Answer (score 0):

*(data+i) and data[i] gives same value.So (*(data+i)).member and data[i].member may also gives same value.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated the 2 are equivalent.
But worth noting there is little risk of misunderstanding with `data[i]` which we automatically read as i-th element of array.
However depending on context it is often easy to forget that `pointer+i` is `pointer+(i*sizeof(whatptrpointsto))` and NOT `pointer+(i bytes)`.